# Filter ng-repeat to find specific value within array of specifications

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of objects, each of which has an array of `Specification`.  I need to filter my objects for a Specification whose name is `"manufacturer"` and whose value matches another variable (for example, a value of `Asus` or `MSI`).

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" translate="{{ 'manufacturer' }}"></label>
  <div class="col-md-10" ng-repeat="componentSpec in search.ComponentSpecifications  | filter:{ SpecificationName: 'manufacturer' }">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="componentSpec">
      <option ng-repeat="manufacturer in adminCtrl.manufacturers" value="{{ manufacturer }}">{{ manufacturer }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<li class="list-group-item col-md-12" ng-repeat="Component in adminCtrl.content  | filter:search">
```

Sample components:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "ASUS GC1",
    "ComponentSpecifications": [
      {
        "SpecificationName": "graphicSize",
        "Value": "20"
      },
      {
        "SpecificationName": "manufacturer",
        "Value": "Asus"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "MSI GC2",
    "ComponentSpecifications": [
      {
        "SpecificationName": "graphicSize",
        "Value": "20"
      },
      {
        "SpecificationName": "manufacturer",
        "Value": "MSI"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: So are you trying to filter for objects that have a manufacturere of a certain value (like `"MSI"`)?

Comment: Can you share your initial approach to solving the problem?